# Recover money in bitcoin

Tags: wallet

I was scammed into putting money into Cash 2 Bitcoin. The money is still sitting at Cash 2 Bitcoin.I have talked to them and they said I needed to get a wallet from Cash app.
The problem I have is Cash app won't assign me a wallet if I don't make a deposit. Cash 2 Bitcoin keeps telling me I can get one but everytime I talk to them the information they give  me doesn't work and are not very hel[pful